# How do you multiply quantity and price within the same array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, multiplication

Here is my multidimensional array

```
<?php
    $total = array (

                      array(
                        "prod_price" => 15,
                        "quantity" => 3
                      ),

                      array(
                        "prod_price" => 8,
                        "quantity" => 2
                      )
?>
```

I'm trying to display all of these in the form of a table

```
<table>
     <tr>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th>Sub Total</th>
     </tr>
     <?php
     foreach($total as $p){
       ?>
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $p["prod_price"];?></td>
       <td><?php echo $p["quantity"]; ?></td>

     </tr>
    <?php
   }
   ?>
   </table>
```

But I have no idea how to multiply quantity and price and display it according to their table like this....
|Price|Quantity|Sub Total|
|:----|:-------|:--------|
|15   | 3      |         |
|8    | 2      |         |

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTMTH.png)

I would love if anyone could give me suggestions to how I could do that by still using the multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Total</td>
   </tr>
   <?php foreach($total as $data){?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['prod_price'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['quantity'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['prod_price'] * $data['quantity'];?></td>
   </tr>    
   <?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Turns out to be a simple solution. Btw, how would you total up the total then after your step?

Comment: Theres a very simple logic on that, i will declare a varibale with initial value 0, and then increase it on every time loop gets executed like below
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Total</td>
   </tr>
   <?php $entireTotal = 0; ?>
   <?php foreach($total as $data){?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['prod_price'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['quantity'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $subTotal = $data['prod_price'] * $data['quantity'];?></td>
   </tr>    
   <?php $entireTotal = $entireTotal + $subTotal;?>
   <?php }?>
</table>